# Soap with WS-Security Java

Tags: java, soap

I need consume a soap ws with ws-security in this format. I did the envolpe great with the jaxb, but the signed information I could not. Is it possible do that?

I tried following [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/dig-signature-api-140772.html) example but without success.

```
<soapenv:Header> 
 <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"> 
 <ds:Signature Id="SIG-4AE8A4927DB1928358141520612833543" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"> 
            <ds:SignedInfo> 
               <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-excc14n#"> 
                  <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ser soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/> 
               </ds:CanonicalizationMethod> 
               <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/> 
               <ds:Reference URI="#id-4AE8A4927DB1928358141520612833442"> 
                  <ds:Transforms> 
                     <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"> 
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ser" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/> 
                     </ds:Transform> 
                  </ds:Transforms> 
                  <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/> 
                  <ds:DigestValue>####</ds:DigestValue> 
               </ds:Reference> 
            </ds:SignedInfo> 
            <ds:SignatureValue>####</ds:SignatureValue> 
            <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-4AE8A4927DB1928358141520612833340"> 
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR4AE8A4927DB1928358141520612833341"> 
                  <ds:X509Data> 
                     <ds:X509IssuerSerial> 
                        <ds:X509IssuerName>####</ds:X509IssuerName> 
                        <ds:X509SerialNumber>####</ds:X509SerialNumber> 
                     </ds:X509IssuerSerial> 
                  </ds:X509Data> 
               </wsse:SecurityTokenReference> 
            </ds:KeyInfo> 
         </ds:Signature> 
         <xenc:EncryptedKey Id="EK-4AE8A4927DB1928358141520612832637" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"> 
            <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaepmgf1p"/> 
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"> 
               <wsse:SecurityTokenReference> 
                  <ds:X509Data> 
                     <ds:X509IssuerSerial> 
                        <ds:X509IssuerName>####</ds:X509IssuerName> 
                        <ds:X509SerialNumber>####</ds:X509SerialNumber> 
                     </ds:X509IssuerSerial> 
                  </ds:X509Data> 
               </wsse:SecurityTokenReference> 
            </ds:KeyInfo> 
            <xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>####</xenc:CipherValue> 
            </xenc:CipherData> 
            <xenc:ReferenceList> 
               <xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-4AE8A4927DB1928358141520612832738"/> 
            </xenc:ReferenceList> 
         </xenc:EncryptedKey>   
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-AFFAF9C28228C497B114031228446232"> 
   <wsu:Created>2014-06-18T20:20:44.623Z</wsu:Created> 
   <wsu:Expires>2014-06-18T20:21:44.623Z</wsu:Expires> 
</wsu:Timestamp> 
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameTokenAFFAF9C28228C497B114031228446111"> 
 <wsse:Username>###################</wsse:Username> 
 <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wssusername-token-profile1.0#PasswordDigest">###################=</wsse:Password> 
 <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">kAnmIripR9VPfury4L9yjg==</wsse:Nonce> 
 <wsu:Created>2014-06-18T20:20:44.511Z</wsu:Created> 
</wsse:UsernameToken> 
</wsse:Security> 
</soapenv:Header>
```

Comment: Do not implement ws-security yourself, you will just reinvent a wheel. As well there are many possible options to make the cannonization and transformation.  So definitely use a mature framework ([CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html) or [Axis2](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jws4/index.html))

Comment: I tried follow that https://github.com/gmazza/blog-samples/tree/master/cxf_x509_profile, but not sucess. I'm only have the url https://www.soc.com.br/WSSoc/FuncionarioModelo2Ws?wsdl, i put on cfx.xml <jaxws:client name="{https://www.soc.com.br/WSSoc/FuncionarioModelo2Ws}FuncionarioModelo2WsPort" createdFromAPI="true">, but can't access the FuncionarioModelo2WsPort, what's wrong?

Comment: if  you say `not sucess` or `can't access` you have to be much more specific (error log, libraries, ...) mybe rather open another question

Comment: I got it, but the problem now is that, how remove &#xd; from ciphervalue?
d00K/eqS/9UU6WsB1/TISj+rLWRf1HI0yDu4xA/00/fQa8w0xN+LKz+rCB87V3dleH67UigjRiMc&#xd;